# Java program involving

Tags: java

I am trying to write the following program sequence.

The first three numbers in the sequence are 1, 1, 2. Every other number in the sequence is the sum of the three previous numbers. The program should prompt the user to enter a limit; the program will stop when the current number in the sequence is greater than or equal to this limit.

For example if I write the limit being 123 I should get: `1 1 2 4 7 13 24 44 81`

I tried the following:

```
import jpb.*;

public class XiaolinSequence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleIO.prompt("Enter a limit on the largest number to be displayed:");
        String userInput = SimpleIO.readLine();
        int counter = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

        int older = 1;
        int old = 1;
        int current = 2;
        while (current < counter) {
            int nextNumber = older + old + current;
            older = old;
            old = current;
            current = nextNumber;
            System.out.println(nextNumber);
        }
    }

}
```

But I am having trouble getting the sequence to print out.

Comment: When I put in say a counter say 123 i do not get the correct output I need

Comment: Please be more descriptive on what you are actual getting as output.

Comment: It looks like it should work. What's the output you're getting?

Comment: looks like an off-by-one, perhaps. You print the next number before checking if its above your limit.

Comment: when I put in say 23 I get 4,7, 13, 24 but I want to get all the numbers kind of like I showed in my post..

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I think he means he is missing `1, 1, 2` and has the extra number at the end.

Comment: If i plug 23 it should be like 1,1,2,4,7,13, like dis how would I make it do that

Comment: Yes Colon D is correct

Comment: So the problems are (i) you're not printing the starting numbers, and (ii) you check that `current < counter` but then calculate and print a new `current` without checking it.

Comment: It helps us if you print out the actual output you're getting as well as the desired output, and an explanation of why it's not what you think it should be.

Comment: Ok my current output is like this                  Enter a limit on the largest number to be displayed:23 4,7,13,24

Comment: @TishaMoisha Just read the answer.

Comment: Didn't finish this quickly enough but @TishaMoisha another solution is here http://ideone.com/f4I4I5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change how you print things.

The missing `1 1 2` are never printed because they are never stored in `nextnumber`, the only variable you ever print.

You will get an additional `149` because you print `nextnumber` without checking it its value is greater than the limit.

For me the output of the following code is `1 1 2 4 7 13 24 44 81` all on new lines.

```
int counter=123; // replaced IO code so I did not have to download the jar.
int older=1;
int old =1;
int current=2;

System.out.println(older);  // prints the first 1
System.out.println(old);  // prints the second 1
System.out.println(current);  // prints the 2

while(current<counter){
    int nextnumber=older+old+current;
    older=old;
    old=current;
    current=nextnumber;
    if(nextnumber <= counter)       
    {
        System.out.println(nextnumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was my initial solution too, at first. But there's a simpler way of doing it. Just print out `older` inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks colin yes your code works and is excellente

Comment: @GCrec, I agree, this code could be improved. I just wanted to illustrate the steps to go from what the OP had to a working a solution.

Comment: one quick question is say I want the output to come out horizontal instead of vertical in the older,older, and current I know you can just remove ln and it will all print on one line but with nextnumber how could you put a comma between those number

Comment: @TishaMoisha For horizontal output use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`.

Comment: @TishaMoisha Before the *while* loop, do this: `System.out.print(older + ", " + old + ", " + current);`. Then inside *if (current < counter)* statement, do this: `System.out.print(", " + nextnumber);`. This will give exactly what you want - horizontal output of comma separated numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Ok since people bashed me for your `SimpleIO`, use whatever you want to read the input. Instead, I'm going to point out a logic flaw in your code.

For the program to function correctly, you need to print out `older` instead of `current`, like so:

```
while (older < counter) 
{
    System.out.println(older);

    final int nextnumber = older + old + current;
    older = old;
    old = current;
    current = nextnumber;
}
```

It works just fine.

---

<strike>There is no such thing as `SimpleIO` in `java.lang`.</strike>

You may want to replace `String userInput = SimpleIO.readLine()` with

```
System.out.print("Enter limit: "); 
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
String userInput = in.next();
```

then the code will work.

Oh and by the way, don't forget to print out `1 1 2` before you start the loop.

Comment: I assumed `SimpleIO` was in `jpb.*`...

Comment: https://github.com/cesardv/Eulers/blob/master/2/jpb/SimpleIO.java

Comment: Fiiiiiine. Edited answer.